# Deliver Adobe Air App to appStore fails

Tags: ios, iphone, apache-flex, air, adobe

I created an Adobe Air iPhone app that I have tested on several iPhones and now try to deliver it to the appStore with a Release Build, but I get all the time, whatever I try (I followed all the instructions as mentioned on this [Adobe help page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS064a3073e805330f6c6abf312e7545f65e-8000.html)) this message in the Apple Application Loader:

> Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate.

This doesn't realy tell me what I do wrong. Is there a way to find out what's the matter?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of AIR which has support for iOS 7?

Comment: @Reboog711 Nothing changed with iOS certs in iOS 7. The only requirement they are rejecting apps on that AIR <3.9 didn't have is icon sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do three things with the packaging of the app to make it past this particular issue:

1. Use an Apple-generated iOS Distribution Certificate. This **must** be generated by the iOS Developer Center. Follow the provided directions in Flash Builder to convert the .cer file into a .p12 file that ADT can use
2. Use an Apple-generated iOS **App Store** Distribution mobile provisioning file. Again, this **must** be generated by the iOS Developer Center
3. Select the "Final Distribution" (or similar, don't have FB open) option in the packaging options (same window you set your certs on)

Beyond that, you may also get rejected for not having the correct icon sizes (Apple will reject any pre-AIR 3.9 app right now because they did not support 120x120 for iPhone) and not having the correct launch images set. (these don't apply to your particular rejection, but they are always worth noting)

Comment: <application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.8"> I guess that's the problem. Need to download latest version of AIR.

Comment: AIR 3.8 shouldn't get rejected for a certs issue. As I mentioned in the reply to Reboog above, iOS 7 did not make any changes to app signing. Your issue is due to one of the three items in the list I provided (though you do need to upgrade to 3.9 if you want Apple to accept it)

Comment: Your sure? Because I've dealt with it thoroughly. Can't it be the 120x120 image?

Comment: Your error message **specifically says** it is an error with your code signing. Apple's errors when submitting apps are actually really good. Once you fixed this error, they would come back with the 120x120 icon error that you would have to fix. So yes, that is a problem. But your current issue is **for sure** your code signing. That is the error Apple is giving you.

Comment: You were right, it's telling the truth. It is just because there are so many steps in the process and I have so many certificates that I oversaw this flaw. In the end it was an issue with the ios_distribution.cer. It was generated with somebody elses .certSigningRequest! Thx!

Answer (score 1):

It very clearly tells you what you're doing wrong, you need to sign the application with a Distribution certificate (these can be generated in the Dev Center).

I would suggest following Apple's [codesigning](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/AppSigning.html) documentation to familiarise yourself with codesigning.

Comment: But familiarized myself with code signing and I used a distribution certificate...